# Java – Unable to target an index in an integer array

Tags: java, arrays

Given an array full of integers, I need to print a sum that excludes the number 13 and also the number that comes immediately after 13, if there is any. For example:

`int[] nums = {1, 1, 13, 1, 13}` is supposed to return a sum of 2.

I looped through the array to exclude the 13's from the final sum, but I don't know how to target the index immediately after the index I'm trying to locate (if it exists). I keep running into "Array Index Out of Bounds Exceptions."

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {

    int[] nums = {1, 1, 13, 1, 13};

    int targetNums = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int sumFixed = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 13) {
            targetNums += nums[i];
        }
        sum += nums[i];
    }

    sumFixed = sum - targetNums;
    System.out.println(sumFixed);
}
```

Comment: But this isn't the code producing an OutOfBoundsException, is it?

Comment: @SebastianS Yeah, it isn't. I took out that portion of the code.

Comment: The current accepted answer doesn't add up to 2.

Answer (score 4):

The code you have posted won't throw an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.  Perhaps you tried something else that did throw that exception.  But it doesn't eliminate the number after the `13`.

If the current number is `13`, add the next number to `targetNums`, being careful not to go off the end of the array with a length check of the next index.

```
if (nums[i] == 13) {
    targetNums += nums[i];

    // Added code
    if (i < nums.length - 1)
    {
        targetNums += nums[i + 1];
    }
    // End added code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {

    int[] nums = {1, 1, 13, 1, 13};

    int sum = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
        if (nums[i] == 13) {
           i++; // skip current and next
        } else {
            sum += nums[i];
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] arguments) {

int[] nums = {1, 1, 13, 1, 13};

int sumFixed = 0;
boolean foundThirteen = false;

for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
    if (nums[i] == 13) {
        foundThirteen = true;
    } else if(!foundThirteen) {
        sumFixed = sumFixed + nums[i];
    }
}
System.out.println(sumFixed);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach using an Iterator. So there is no need to deal with indexes or flags.

```
Iterator<Integer> iter = Arrays.asList(nums).iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    Integer num = iter.next();
    if (num == 13) {
        targetNums += num;
        if (iter.hasNext()) {
            targetNums += iter.next(); // not sure if you want to add this to targetNums, too...
        }
    } else {
        sum += num;
    }
}
```